# 3 php arrays merged and displayed by date

Tags: php, arrays, date, merge

If I had multiple arrays/objects of data pulled from different sources like a facebook feed, twitter feed, and blog feed, how would I merge them in order to display them as a mixed set sorted by date?

Comment: [`array_merge()`](http://us.php.net/array_merge) the arrays into one, then use [`usort()`](http://us.php.net/usort) with a custom sorting function that knows how to extract date from each type of object and compare two dates.

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate through each array and convert the various time formats to a common one, probably a unix timestamp like this

```
strtotime($time);
```

Then use that as the key to the array:

```
foreach ($fb_arrays as $fb_array) {
  $key = strtotime($fb_array['time']);
  $fb_array_by_time[$key] = $fb_array;
}
```

Then I would

```
array_merge($array_one_by_time, $array_two_by_time, $array_three_by_time);
```

Then I would

`asort()` or `rasort()` depending on the direction you want to sort by

**Edit:**

To avoid collisions you can do this

```
foreach ($events as $event) {
  $key = strtotime($event['time']);
  $key .= $network;
  $n = 0;
  while (isset($event_by_time[$key . $n])) { $n++; }
  $event_by_time[$key . $n] = $event;
}
```

then the keys should be like:

```
123134223facebook0
123134223twitter0
123134225facebook0
123134225facebook1
```

after sorting with `asort()`

Comment: What if there are two events in one array with the same timestamp? `:)`

Comment: In theory none would be the same time especially given seconds in the timestamp but i guess it isn't 100% bulletproof!

Comment: or... to group networks together you might want to make the `key = $key . $n . $network`